# Forced to reinstall Python packages after every deployment (Flask + Azure App Service)

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am running an Azure App Service on Python (Flask based) which requires a lot of Python packages to work. I wanted to ask if there is any way to prevent reinstalling them every time I deploy my app? I am using the "az webapp up" command to deploy the app and it seems to reset my server to its initial state after each deployment (which doesn't come built in with the modules I need).

I used a Linux App Service. My problem is that I need to reinstall all my Python packages (for ex. Pandas) each time I deploy the image. My ideal purpose is to avoid this, i.e. I want the packages I install once to stay installed.

Comment: What type of Azure App Service did you use, for Windows or Linux? It sounds like you deployed your app to Azure App Service on Linux by following the offical tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash, Right? If so, your app was built as a Docker image to deploy, so it's new every time. What's your real problem I want to know? Please update your post for more details and your real purpose.

Comment: @PeterPan I used a Linux App Service. My problem is that I need to reinstall all my packages each time I deploy the image. My ideal purpose is to avoid this, i.e. I want the packages I install once to stay installed.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the --plan parameter Name as well for the web site to target the existing website for any kind of update, otherwise it would create a new website starting from the scratch.

It's a know bug for the below command:

```
az webapp up --sku F1 -n <app-name> -l <location-name>
```

Additional reference:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9955

This issue has been in priority list to fix it, you can check the above github link for updates.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really. Even without the --sku or --plan parameters, the command identifies the correct existing app service to update. It even says - "The command will deploy contents to the existing app".